# Setting CKEDITOR.config.contentAllowed to true still removes classes

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Installed CKEDITOR 4.5.7. Using Chrome v47 browser. I need to allow clients to enter certain HTML elements with classes. I still have a basic install and have set the following in config.js.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

    console.log(config);
};
```

I can see both settings get set on console and the editor UI color changes. However, CKEDITOR still strips all classes from DIV elements.

Read many questions/articles on this issue and clearing cache seems to resolve for most; I've cleared cache with no luck.

I tried this configuration to tempt CKEDITOR to leave a few classes alone on DIV elements; again, the UI changes color but the editor continues to strip classes.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'div(col-md-*,container-fluid,row)';

    console.log(config);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies to CKEDITOR! We discovered a reference to JSOUP in backend services which was stripping out the classes on all elements. We revised the backend code and left the configuration above and all is working as expected now.